# Distance between point and hyperplane given basis

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, gram-schmidt

I used the Gram-Schmidt process to find the orthonormal basis for some hyperplane, $V$, in $\mathbb{R}^4$. The vectors are
$$
u = \begin{bmatrix}1\\
0\\
0\\
0\end{bmatrix}, v = \begin{bmatrix}1\\
1\\
1\\
0\end{bmatrix}, w = \begin{bmatrix}1\\
2\\
0\\
1\end{bmatrix}
$$

I end up getting the basis
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\
0\\
0\\
0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\\
\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The next part of the question is Calculate the distance from the point $p_0 = (1, 0, 1, 0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $V$.

Since this is $\mathbb{R}^4$, I can no longer use the cross product, so I don't know where to go from here. Something about this tells me it should be rather easy.

Answer (score 0):

First find all vectors $r$ orthogonal to $u,v,w.$ I found $r=r_2(0,1,-1,-2).$ Then consider the line orthogonal to $V$ passing through $p=(1,0,-1,0).$ Its points are parameterized by $r_2$ and have the form $p_{r_2}=(1,r_2,1-r_2,-2r_2).$ Next find $r_2=t$ such that $p_{t}$ belongs to $V$, that is find $a,b,c$ and $t$ such that $p_{t}=au+bv+cw.$ Solve this linear system with 4 equations and four unknown $a,b,c,t.$ Finally compute $\|p-p_t\|^2.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$ be composed of the orthonormal vectors you found, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
P = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{3} \\
0 & 1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{3} \\
0 & 0 & 1/\sqrt{3}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Then the projection matrix on V is given by $\operatorname{Proj}_V = PP^T$. The projection of $p_0$ on $V$ is then given by $p_{\parallel} = \operatorname{Proj}_V p_0$, then $\|p_0 - p_{\parallel}\|$ is the desired answer.

Motivation behind projection matrix:

The projection of $\vec{p}_0$ on $V$ is given by $\vec{p}_{\parallel} = (\vec{p}_0 \cdot \vec{v}_1)\vec{v}_1 + (\vec{p}_0 \cdot \vec{v}_2)\vec{v}_2 + (\vec{p}_0 \cdot \vec{v}_3)\vec{v}_3$, where $\vec{v}_i$ are the orthonormal vectors you found. You can verify that the $\operatorname{Proj}_V \vec{p}_0$ above gives exactly the same formula:

\begin{equation*}
PP^T \vec{p}_0 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\vert & \vert & \vert \\
\vec{v}_1 & \vec{v}_2 & \vec{v}_3 \\
\vert & \vert & \vert
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-\;\ \vec{v}_1\ - \\
-\;\ \vec{v}_2\ - \\
-\;\ \vec{v}_3\ - \\
\end{pmatrix}
\vec{p}_0 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\vert & \vert & \vert \\
\vec{v}_1 & \vec{v}_2 & \vec{v}_3 \\
\vert & \vert & \vert
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{p}_0 \cdot \vec{v}_1 \\
\vec{p}_0 \cdot \vec{v}_2 \\
\vec{p}_0 \cdot \vec{v}_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Upon expanding gives exactly what we are looking for, i.e., $(\vec{p}_0 \cdot \vec{v}_1)\vec{v}_1 + (\vec{p}_0 \cdot \vec{v}_2)\vec{v}_2 + (\vec{p}_0 \cdot \vec{v}_3)\vec{v}_3$

Comment: What is the motivation behind forming the projection matrix

Comment: @currentexplanation Please check my edit.